# How to understand this redirection command?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

`find /home -name .bashrc > list 2>&1`

I learn from book that the above command is to redirect the output of find into a file called list including both STDOUT and STDERR. (Particularly, all things in STDOUT will be outputted in front of STDERR.)

And I know that 2 is STDERR, 1 is STDOUT.

But I'm having problem with "parsing" and understanding the `> list 2>&1` part?
And What is `2>&1`?

Comment: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/

Comment: Send 1 to list and send 2 to where 1 is being send to (also list). Compare with `2>&1 > list` : Send 2 to where 1 is being send to (the console) and send 1 to list.

Answer (score 1):

`> list` redirects the command's standard out to the file `list`.

`2>&1` [redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles) your standard error to standard out. In this case, standard out is the file `list`, so `list` will contain all output and errors your `find` command generates.

Further read: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html